# The tangent and normal cones of a convex set are polar of each other

Tags: convex-analysis

If $K$ is a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, then for any $x \in K$, we have the following result:
$$
\mathcal{T}(x;K)^{*}=-\mathcal{N}(x;K),
$$
where $\mathcal{T}(x;K)$ is the tangent cone of $K$ at $x$, $\mathcal{T}(x;K)^{*}$ is the dual cone of $\mathcal{T}(x;K)$, is defined by
$$
\mathcal{T}(x;K)^{*}=\{d : v^{\top}d \geq 0, \forall \ v \in \mathcal{T}(x;K)\},
$$
and $\mathcal{N}(x;K)$ is normal cone of $K$ at $x$, is defined by
$$
\mathcal{N}(x;K)=\{d:d^{\top}(y-x) \leq 0, \forall \ y \in K\}.
$$
I am stucking in proving $\mathcal{T}(x;K)^{*} \supseteq -\mathcal{N}(x;K)$, but failed. Let $d \in \mathcal{N}(x;K)$, then we have
$$
d^{\top}(y-x) \leq 0, \forall \ y \in K.
$$
If we can prove $d^{\top}y \leq 0$ for all $y \in K$, then the conclusion follows. Any help would be appreciated.